# Cookie is null when i set setHttpOnly and setSecure to true

Tags: spring-boot, cookies, jwt, session-cookies

I have springboot application where i'm setting JWT to Cookies as shown below which gets expires after hour. In this case `setHttpOnly` and `setSecure` is false.

```
Cookie sessionCookie = new Cookie("invsessionId", token);
```

Eveything is working fine.Whenever API call is made, i'm checking the token by accessing token via cookie header as shown below

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

            if (cookies == null || cookies.length < 1) {
                throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Invalid Token");
            }

            Cookie sessionCookie = null;
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if ((jwtConfig.getPrefix()).equals(cookie.getName())) {
                    sessionCookie = cookie;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // TODO: move the cookie validation into a private method
            if (sessionCookie == null || StringUtils.isEmpty(sessionCookie.getValue())) {
                throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Invalid Token");
            }
```

But when I `setHttpOnly` and `setSecure` to true and make an API call, `request.getCookies()` is always `null`. I check a lot before posting here, not able to find the solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a secure connection?

Comment: @M.Deinum As of now i'm not using. But planning to implement. I even set setSecure to false and setHttpOnly to true, still same behaviour

Comment: Using `setSecure` without an SSL connection will not work. How is the request being made?

Comment: Basically the request should be sent from the front javascript ajax call, but as of now i'm using the postman. You mean say without SSL if we set both setHttpOnly and setSecure to true, it won't work?

Comment: That is the whole point of `setSecure` to only transport cookies over secure connections, hence SSL is a requirement. `setHttpOnly` shouldn't prevent a cookie from being send, but that might depend on your subsequent requests in postman. You cannot read the cookie anymore. So if you read and copy the cookie that won't work anymore (as that is what HttpOnly is for).

Comment: @M.Deinum ok Thanks. Yes, i need to read the cookie in the other api call since i will be using the cookie to authenticate user. So if i set setHttpOnly to true then it doesn't work? this is what you are saying right? then what's the approach?

Comment: with `HttpOnly` only the originating server can read the cookie, you cannot read it from the client and pass it on. That is the whole point of `HttpOnly`. I strongly suggest a read of what those different things mean in the context of a Cookie instead of just blindly setting them to true and wondering why things stopped working.